# How to use Cadence with multiple microservices

Tags: cadence-workflow

I'm trying to understand how Cadence engine works, but I cannot understand how to make it distributed. I already have experience with Conductor, and in that case I just have to implement the Worker class for each microservice and then point to the uri of the Conductor server to start polling. How can I make the same thing with Cadence?

Comment: sembra una richiesta di lavoro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate parts of distributing Cadence. The first is that Cadence backend service is itself a scalable distributed RPC service. It is scaled out by adding more machines (or mostly pods these k8s days) and by adding database capacity.

The second part is scaling out workers that implement workflows and activities. The workers connect to the service. So in Cadence you have to initialize connection to the Cadence service endpoint (through host:ip, DNS or custom discovery mechanism) and start worker that gets tasks from Cadence using long poll. The workers are stateless and you can add and remove them any time.